# Premature end of script headers: php-cgi -- While running a CURL script

Tags: php, curl

before i go back to the Host (yet again) the only error log they are giving on the below script is:

Premature end of script headers: php-cgi

the scrip i am running which works on other servers and my local machine is but on this perticualr server is giving an error 500:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://feeds.energydigger.com/headlines.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

if(isset($doc->channel))
{
    parseRSS($doc);
}
function parseRSS($xml)
{
    $cnt = 3;
    for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
    {
        $url    = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
        $title  = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
        $desc = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
        $date = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

        echo '<p><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a><br />'.$date.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what may generate the error, I can't say I have seen this one before... i am still trying to get hold of the PHP logs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a 500 error, if an exception is thrown and not caught, and in PHP settings `display_errors` = 0. Most likely it is thrown by SimpleXML. Try wrapping the portion with XML operations in a `try .. catch` block and see what the exception is. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://feeds.energydigger.com/headlines.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

try
{
    $doc = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    if(isset($doc->channel))
    {
        parseRSS($doc);
    }
    function parseRSS($xml)
    {
        $cnt = 3;
        for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
        {
            $url    = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
            $title  = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $desc = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
            $date = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

            echo '<p><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a><br />'.$date.'</p>';
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

Just in case, [here's more about PHP exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: ah yes the exceptions i totally forgot about that, uploaded the above and still gives me 500 page with

[Thu Apr 18 14:37:31 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Thu Apr 18 14:37:31 2013] [error] [client 194.168.131.146] Premature end of script headers: php-cgi

Comment: In that case, the read data timeout may mean an unresponsive server on the other end of the URL (the one you're getting your feed from), or the feed XML may take too much time parsing (SimpleXML loads the entire file into memory and parses it as a whole on instantialization.)

Can you check if the URL is actually reachable from that server that has the problem?

Comment: right sorry for the delay (been afk). so i tried a simple get headers and locally and on another server and it brings back a 200 response, on the problem server it brings back a error 500 again. i am lost here. now its not a curl issue i have created another post, thank you for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200928/server-x-brings-back-200-response-server-y-throws-and-internal-server-error