# server X brings back 200 response, Server Y throws and Internal server error

Tags: php, curl

I'm having an issue with a CURL reader I built (see:  [Premature end of script headers: php-cgi -- While running a CURL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080086/premature-end-of-script-headers-php-cgi-while-running-a-curl-script))

The guy said to check if my problem server will speak to the feed, so I tested the below code locally and it works, tested in on the server and got an internal server error. I am lost here, how should I go about debug this as the host company are not being very helpful at all.

code:

```
$url = 'http://www.energydigger.com/feeds/headlines.xml';
list($status) = get_headers($url);
if (strpos($status, '200') !== FALSE) {
   echo 'boom';
}
```

**problem server response:**
*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*

all i am getting from the log they provide is:

```
[Wed Apr 24 20:36:01 2013] [warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[Wed Apr 24 20:36:01 2013] [error] [client 151.227.255.54] Premature end of script headers: php-cgi
```

Any advice is appreciated, as I'm a little stuck on what to do now.

Comment: Is this the complete script?

Comment: the above is a test for me to see whats going on, on the problem server, as said it brings back a 200 localy, see other post for full CURL thing, i was simply trying to see if Y server would see the feed. it just brings back a internal server error

Comment: I was running into this error in a different situation.  It was due to file permissions on the server.

Comment: @Matt. file, folder or just general... not a LAMP person more a windows... thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I could reproduce it. But my environment uses mod_fcgid not simple cgi. Make sure the owner and group are the same as for the executing cgi user. Or for simplicity as all the other files in your webdirectory.